# Trying to wrap dispatch function in react redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi recently I encountered the useDispatch hook that supposed to give me an alternative to mapDispatchToProps, and I found very repetitive to do `() => dispatch(action(args))` in each onPress so I started to think about something generic. My goal was to make a hook that uses `useDispatch()` and wraps the functions that it gets and retuens `() => dispatch(theWrappedAction(theActionArgs))`
for example if I have an action `upCounterActionCreator` that is as following:

```
export const upCounterActionCreator = (count: number = 1): AppActions => {
const action: UpCounterAction = {
    type: 'UP_COUNTER',
    count
};
return action;
};
```

My goal is to do something like this:
`const [upAfterDispatch] = useActions(upCounterActionCreator);`

and then I can do:

```
<Button onPress={upAfterDispatch(1)} title='+' />
```

What I tried to do is as following:

```
export const useActions = (...actions: ((...args: any) => AppActions)[]) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<AppActions>>();
const actionsWithDispach: ((...args: any) => () => (...args: any) => AppActions)[] = [];

actions.forEach(action => {
    actionsWithDispach.push((...args: any) => () => (...args: any) => dispatch(action(...args)));
});
return actionsWithDispach;
```

};

to put that wrapped function on onPress I need to do

`<Button onPress={upAfterDispatch(1)()} title='+' />` - to invoke it, it is not so good option. 
Then when I do call it the action indeed is being dispatched however when I debug on my payload I have an object insted of count that is as following:
it is a class-

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to to in order to:

1. get the number 1(the count parameter sent  in the action payload) instead of the class
2. invoke the returned functions from useActions and not call it like this `onPress={upAfterDispatch(1)()`

** I think that the object received in the args is the react native onPress event, how to avoid it overriding my count argument?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to do:

```
export const useActions = (...actions: ((...args: any) => AppActions)[]) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<AppActions>>();
  const actionsWithDispach: ((...args: any) => () => (...args: any) => AppActions)[] = [];

  actions.forEach(action => {
    actionsWithDispach.push((...args: any) => () => dispatch(action(...args)));
  });
  return actionsWithDispach;
};
```

You added an extra `(...args: any) =>` but with the code above you can do `onClick={theAction(1)}`

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
};
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === 'UP') {
    return { count: state.count + payload };
  }
  return state;
};
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  { ...initialState },
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
//action
const add = (howMuch) => ({ type: 'UP', payload: howMuch });
const useAction = (action) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return React.useMemo(
    () => (...args) => () => dispatch(action(...args)),
    [action, dispatch]
  );
};
const Button = React.memo(function Button({ up, howMuch }) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <button onClick={up(howMuch)}>
      Rendered: {rendered.current} times, add {howMuch}
    </button>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const up = useAction(add);
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.count);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>count:{count}</h2>
      <Button up={up} howMuch={1} />
      <Button up={up} howMuch={1} />
      <Button up={up} howMuch={1} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @MD10 If it doesn't work then you did something wrong, I added a working code snippet with the exact code as in my answer. Doing it this way would cause unnecessary renders though because your actions are re created every time even if they don't need to be created. You can use a useMemo in your useActions to prevent that.

Comment: I didn't pay attention, you were right ! Thnaks a lot you are the best! Can you please show me how to use useMemo here please? just wrap the entire function? what is the purpose of it ?

Comment: @MD10 I updated the answer but with useMemo you can only do one action at the time or it'll re create the actions even if the actions didn't change. In the example you can see the buttons are not re rendered because they are pure components (using React.memo) and the up action never changes (using useMemo)

Comment: thanks again, can you explain why useMemo is possible only if I get only one action?

Comment: Also, even if didnt do this hook and used arrow functions in onPress there would be unnecessary renders, right? How bad is it to leave it like that?

Comment: @MD10 `useMemo` doesn't work with multiple args because `...args` creates a new array every time the hook is called. So even though the elements in the array are the same useMemo sees it as a new array and will not memoize the dispatching action functions. To not memoize does not have to be a big performance hit, it depends on how often unnecessary renders happen and how many elements are re rendered. It also depneds on your target platform, low end phone will suffer more than high end desktop.

Comment: tried to use your useAction with useMemo, however when I did  this 
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-eq6z0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
it still renders each time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213545/discussion-between-md10-and-hmr).

Comment: @MD10 The sandbox has no runnable code but Counter is a functional component and not a pure component, did you forget React.memo(Counter)?

Comment: I did export default React.memo(Counter); still foesnt work

Comment: also wrappeed the function itself with React.memo

Comment: all tried to 
const upCounter = useActions(upCounterActionCreator);
  const callBack = useCallback(upCounter,[upCounterActionCreator]);
doesnt work either

Comment: @MD10 You have the sandbox but I don't see any code there demonstrating your problem. There is a file with some lines of code that doesn't do anything. Not sure what you expect to "solve" with only offering the information you are currently offering. This happens so often on SO they even felt the need to create [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to generate a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Comment: you are right, my bad- here you go :
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wright-tpkd0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
as you can see each time I click on up the component renders agin despite using useCallback and useMemo iin useActions as you did

Comment: @MD10 I made the button it's own component, your component re renders because counter is changing, not because up is changing.

Comment: ok thanks, but when I did this without the useMemo and the counter the component didn't rerender.. why is that? you told me that on each time an action is created it causes a rerender https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wright-tpkd0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @MD10 A component will re render when state is changed, when context is changed and it uses `useContext`, when the value returned from `useSelector` has changed or when props passed to it have changed. In your example none of these things happen so Counter is not re rendered.

Comment: I understood from you that the useActions() will create the arrow functions again and again and that will cause a rerender.. 
"Doing it this way would cause unnecessary renders though because your actions are re created every time even if they don't need to be created."

Comment: @MD10 If you do `<Child onChange={()=>console.log('hello')} />` in Parent then you always pass a new reference for onChange to that component even though what the callback does never changes. But when Parent never re renders then neither does Child. In my example I have a component called App that re renders every time count changes but the Button components in App never re render because what they do when clicked stays the same.

Comment: so if I didn't have counter and only called useActions that generated me the actions that I pass to onClick , it wolnt have caused a rerender ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
type ActionCreator = (...args: any) => AppActions
export const useActions = (...actions: ActionCreator[]) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<AppActions>>();
  return actions.map(action => (...args: any) => () => dispatch(action(...args)))
}
```

Comment: works if I add () => before the call thus it it doenst achieve what I intended :/

Comment: Want to avoid using () => always

Comment: The comment above solved my issue, just trying to figure how to use the useMemo hook and why - as suggested above - of you can provide an answer to that I would be grateful, thanks though!